# Application runs fine on Eclipse emulator but errors on the phone - FroYo

Tags: android, eclipse, exception, emulation, android-2.2-froyo

I've got an application which (although I'm not sure why,) requires Android 2.2 at least to work, so after getting Froyo on my phone, I tested the application and although it installs and begins to run, when I carry out a function, it results in the following error:

> "The application  has stopped unexpected. Please try again."

It works fine on the emulator which is also running Froyo so I can't figure out what the problem is. The error in adb logcat is the following:

> W/dalvikvm( 1027): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x2aacc8a0)

And it gives a null pointer exception, except I know that there isn't a null pointer exception as it works fine in the emulator and I can see from the System.out in adb logcat that the value won't be null.

Does anyone have any idea on what I can do to fix this?

Thank you for your time!

Edit: Here is the stack as requested:

> W/dalvikvm(  861): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x2aacc8a0)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(  861): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   E/AndroidRuntime(  861): java.lang.NullPointerException
>   E/AndroidRuntime(  861):    at com.andrWow.wCraftArmory.Armory.updateUI(Armory.java:150)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(  861):    at com.andrWow.wCraftArmory.Armory.access$2(Armory.java:140)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(  861):    at com.andrWow.wCraftArmory.Armory$carryOutSearch.onPostExecute(Armory.java:282)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(  861):    at com.andrWow.wCraftArmory.Armory$carryOutSearch.onPostExecute(Armory.java:1)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(  861):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(  861):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(  861):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(  861):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(  861):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(  861):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(  861):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(  861):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(  861):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:876)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(  861):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:634)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(  861):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   W/ActivityManager(  123):   Force finishing activity com.andrWow.wCraftArmory/.Armory

Here is the code around line 150 - The second line is line 150:

```
PlayerCharacter toon = worker.getToons().get(latestToon[0] + "&" + latestToon[1]); 
LinkedHashMap<String, LinkedHashMap<String, String>> bM = toon.getCategoryMap("baseStats");
```

It only gets this far if the result of assigning "toon" is not going to be null. The result of getCategoryMap with that key also shouldn't be null because it's pretty much hardcoded to adding a value with that key when it is created. getCategoryMap is a getter which checks the HashMap contains that key, if it doesn't, it would give an error into the system.out which isn't there.

***Solved edit:***

Thanks for your help everyone.
I really didn't think it was a fault with the code because I knew it worked on the emulator and I had it running once on the phone too but it turns out it was a fault with my code. After getting FroYo, I set it up which included adding a new keyboard which automatically changed the case of the first letter so it was a matter of me not handling upper/lower cases properly - a silly mistake.

Thanks for your time, really appreciated!

Comment: Hi Dave post more info of your stack trace

Comment: Yes, we need more info. However, when you're working with emulators and real devices (and this is true for iPhone, Android, Blackberry, WP7 etc.) it's not surprising when an app works in one place but not in the other. It's *more* surprising when something works fine on both.

Comment: You can't be sure there's not a null pointer exception when the VM is throwing a null pointer exception. There's obviously a null pointer somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for all your feedback, I've posted the exception stack although I'm not sure how much help it'll be. And yes, I guess you are right about the null pointer being present, I should have said that I can't figure how it can be null.

Comment: @Dave you need to show us the lines of code around the null pointer exception, at like 150 of Armory.java.  And please point out exactly which line of code that is.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the obvious answer is that `PlayerCharacter toon = worker.getToons().get(latestToon[0] + "&" + latestToon[1]);`  is returning null.

To figure out exactly why you can break it down into a few steps.  What does `latestToon[0] + "&" + latestToon[1]` give you?  Is it what you expect?  I assume `getToons()` returns a map of some sort?  What are the contents of it?

Comment: Thanks for this. I like to think it was your questioning that made me wonder and test this out - it wasn't the fault of the emulator or FroYo, it was a stupid mistake I made.. I thought I had controlled the (upper/lower) case of the parameters but obviously not well enough, what was putting me off was that I knew it worked once and then something changed, the thing being that I got a new keyboard which automatically caps the first word, (I initially thought it was something to do with the keyboard itself) but it was just the case so thanks for your help everyone, appended my original post.